# Call history in Cisco Unity

Tags: cisco, voip

I am looking for call records of a specific user (seeing when they called a specific number and duration) using the Cisco VoIP service.

I've tried looking at the CDR Analysis (similar post [How to view call history for users on Cisco Unified Communications Manager?](https://serverfault.com/q/350821/128087)).

Is there another/better way to find this information, the only search criteria here is date-time and the results are not sortable/filterable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that you can export the records to a text file but that strips out a lot of the data.

I ended up searching for the number that was called rather than sifting through the callers whole call history. There is a view link in the CDR-CMR Dump column that will display some more details and that is where I found the time connected and disconnected.